# how to get fraction as it is ( without getting itssimplest fraction )? i vainly tried using this:

Tags: python-3.x, fractions

```
x=7
y=14
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(7/14))
```

I got answer 1/2 but I needed 7/14. is there any way to write as it is without using string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most fraction libraries will simplify the numerator and denominator as soon as they are created as a performance optimization. If you are working with large unsimplified fractions there is a chance that they will overflow. So before each operation the fractions will have to be simplified anyway.

If you want to keep the original numerator and denominator intact you should create your own wrapper class like so:

```
class MyFraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator=1, denominator=1):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def get_fraction(self):
        from fractions import Fraction
        return Fraction(numerator=self.numerator, denominator=self.denominator)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.numerator, self.denominator)

f = MyFraction(numerator=7, denominator=14)
print(f)  # prints 7/14
print(f.get_fraction())  # prints 1/2
```

Note: You should be invoking fraction using the [Fraction(numerator=0, denominator=1)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) constructor.

Is your case what is happening is:

`Fraction(7/14) => Fraction(0.5) => 1/2`

Comment: Why not import a  module in a method? The keyword arguments match the constructor from the fraction library

Comment: Try the code and run MyFraction(7, 14), it works :). Also imports in python are [cached](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Because it now supports both constructors and I can have sensible defaults. Again I just copied the python library implementation...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89465/discussion-between-anarci-and-poke).